# Stop wordpress automatically escaping $_POST data

Tags: security, forms

I have a custom front end form which creates a custom post type post and have just discovered WordPress automatically escapes $_POST data in the same way that Magic Quotes does.

I have Magic Quotes disabled and have created a test form that I run on the same domain. When run on it's own, no data is escaped. However when I run it as a page template for a WordPress page the raw $_POST data is escaped, i.e. using print_r($_POST) so before there has been any processing done.

I have also tried this with multiple themes and the same result.

Anyone know where / how to shut this off? Is there a filter I can suppress for this form?

Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

No, but you can just run [stripslashes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) on it.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I've done that already. Wanted to overide it because of all the reasons not to use Magic Quotes but I guess in WP the environment is always the same so it's not the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

Worth having a read of the trac bug here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18322

In short, you can use [stripslashes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) as onetrickpony already mentioned, or [wp_unslash](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_unslash/), to remove the slashes from your $_POST vars.